Syncfusion WinForms SfCombobox Search for item and select it programmatically
I'm trying to fins and select an item programmatically. Just like the regular find string functionality in the standard combo box.
SfComboBox.SelectedIndex = SfCombobox.FindString("Houston")

I have search in google and the syncfusion documentation for a sample code and no luck.
